# Filter hasMany Results by WHERE Clause in Grails 3

Tags: hibernate, grails

I have a grails Domain Class like this

```
class ClassRoom {

    Integer Id
    String classRoomName
    Date dateDeleted

    static hasMany = [students: Student]

}

class Student {
     String studentName
     Date dateDeleted
}
```

Suppose if i print all students of a classRoom 1 from ClassRoom.
`println ClassRoom.findByIdAndDateDeletedIsNull(1).students` It will print all the students who have dateDeleted as well. 
Is there any way to filter out the records who have dateDeleted SET?

Comment: Because ClassRoom.findByIdAndDateDeletedIsNull(1) returns ClassRoom Object which dateDeleted is null and id is 1.You should only use ClassRoom.get(1) to get that object.Do filter that object to find all Student which  dateDeleted is null .

Answer (score 2):

The following will return to you the list of students

```
ClassRoom.executeQuery("""
        select s 
          from ClassRoom c
          join c.students s
         where c.id = :id 
           and c.dateDeleted is null
           and s.dateDeleted is null
""", [id: id])
```

Comment: for SQL databases

Answer (score 1):

Filtering result:

```
ClassRoom.findByIdAndDateDeletedIsNull(1).students.findAll{!it.dateDeleted}
```

Comment: Does this get all the results from the database and then filter by dateDeleted? Or get Only the ones that are not deleted? I want to know if there is a way to not Load Unnecessary Objects.

Comment: It filter all results for not deleted ClassRoom number 1

Comment: This loads the full students collection when that is not necessary